# Format multiple findall statements with beautifulsoup into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to make a pandas DataFrame out of some data that I scraped off of a website and I've used find_all multiple time but is there a way to make multiple find_all statements and separate the results into a pandas dataframe. More generally, can I create the dataframe with fewer lines of code. Here is an example of a row in the dataframe with my current code:

96 | AGI | $0.03 | $1.92 | 4.61%

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cryptoCompareSoup = BeautifulSoup('A LOT OF HTML HERE', 'html.parser')
cryptoCompareDataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Name':[item.text.strip() for item in cryptoCompareSoup.find_all('span',{'class':'mobile-name ng- binding'})],
                                               'Price':[item.text.strip() for item in cryptoCompareSoup.find_all('div', {'class':['current-price-value ng-binding','current-price-value ng-binding highlight-down value-down','current-price-value ng-binding highlight-up value-up']})],
                                               'Volume':[item.text.strip() for item in cryptoCompareSoup.find_all('td',{'class':'full-volume col-selected'})],
                                               '24HrDelta':[item.findChild('span').text.strip() for item in cryptoCompareSoup.find_all('td',{'ng-class':["{'col-selected':tableColumns[6].sortApplied}"]})]
                                               })
```

Comment: Use a dictionary and function

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code right now?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my code right now. I wanted to see if there was a way to make the dataframe with fewer lines either through combining all of the findall statements into a single line and have an array of key values and insert them into the dataframe iteratively for instance.

Comment: Got it; so can you add a couple of the html snippets, including the one that resulted in your example row?